# I have a problem with JavaScript onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have started doing a game, kinda similar to 'Spend Bill Gates Money', but I've said to change it up a bit.
I've done the first item, and I've tried to edit it with JS, so everytime you press "Buy", it will remove 1 dollar from you, or, when you press "Sell" to give you 1 dollar. The problem is, everytime I click, it only counts once. Plus, if I press "Buy", then "Sell", it gives me instantly 11 dollars, instead of 10 dollars.
Filename: index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<title>Spend you own money</title>
<script src="script.js">

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
<noscript>You need to enable javascript in order to have fun!</noscript>

<h1 class="center" id = "money">Money Left: 10</h1><!--Money = 100 000 000 000-->
<div class= "main">
    <div class="pen">
    <h2>Pen</h2>
    <input type="submit" class="sell" value="Sell" onclick="sellpen()">
   <!-- <input type="text" class="amount" value = 0 id = "amountpen" readonly="readonly" size="9%"> -->
    <input type="submit" class="buy" value="Buy" onclick="amountpen()" >
    </div>
</div>
      


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Filename: script.js

```js
var money = 10; //dollars
var pen = 1; // dollar
var mpen = money-pen;
var ppen = money+pen;
function amountpen() {
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " + mpen;
     money = money-1;
}
function sellpen() {
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " +ppen;
    money = money+
```

Comment: please post your full script.js file? it seems unfinished!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with this JS code :

```
money = 10; //dollars
function amountpen() {
    money--;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " + money;
}
function sellpen() {
    money++;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " +money;
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot the different than an answer. What did you change? **Why** should it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your script.js would be like this:

```
var money = 10; 
var pen = 1; 
function amountpen() {
     var mpen = money-pen;
     document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " + mpen;
     money = money-1;
}
function sellpen() {
    var ppen = money+pen;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money Left: " +ppen;
    money = money+1;
}
```